# Excel - Create dataframe out of raw data with multiple columns

Tags: excel

In this question I will be writing some text, but also referring to a picture linked below.

I have raw data, with **indicators** (can be more than 4) always in column C.
In the raw data, I also have **Company IDs** (can be more than 2) always in row 5.
When these cross, they get some values. For instance, Company ID 1s value on indicator1 is 10.

I also have a list which takes the unique Company IDs on row 5.

I would like to create a dataframe which puts these values on table form, with each row representing a combination of indicator, company and the actual value - like represented in "desired outcome".

I would also like that table to be dynamic with how many indicators are in column C and how many companies are in row 5.

I need help with which formula to put in the three columns in desired outcome.
I have tried some combinations of xlookup, index match and byrow, but I cant seem to find a solution.

In advance, thank you :)

[image: Picture link]

Comment: Same question as before: how do you identify the company IDs from ? Do you have a list or how do they distinguish from the "Random Text"? Which Excel version do you have

Comment: Hi Ike. Thank you. Excel version 2208. The company IDs will be in row 5, and there will not be any other values than company IDs in that row, from column E and onwards. The list of unique company IDs will be dynamic.